# Strict-aliasing optimization benefits in benchmarks?

Tags: performance, gcc, clang, benchmarking, strict-aliasing

Is there any information on type-based alias analysis (strict-aliasing rule) improving performance, for either gcc or clang compiler, on Spec2006, Spec2017 or other commonly used benchmark suite?

Comment: The effect of such optimizations, or the cost of disabling them, will depend a lot upon how code is written.  I'd like to see some stats on the real-world performance differences between gcc-style `-fstrict-aliasing`, and that of icc (which can correctly process many programs for which gcc and clang would require `-fno-strict-aliasing`).  Performance on benchmarks, however, isn't apt to be meaningful because it will show whatever the creators of the benchmarks want it to show.